# Call angular build from another directory

Tags: angular, ant, angular-cli

I am working on an application that where Ant is used for compilation. I put the Angular in a folder inside the root directory of that application. So in the application root, say it's called $APP_ROOT, I have a build.xml. I want to put the "ng build" command in there, but I can't seem to run that command anywhere outside of the angular directory, which is in $APP_ROOT/Angular. Is there a way I can call the "ng build" command from the $APP_ROOT directory so I can add it to my build.xml?